# Como criptografar no projeto Java Web

Tags: java, jsf, criptografia

Alguém pode me passar algum material com a forma mais segura de fazer a segurança de um sistema?

Estou querendo colocar isso no cadastro do usuário no meu projeto JSF com Primefaces 5.1 para quando for cadastrado salvar a senha já criptografada no banco de dados.

Comment: Procurei por [Criptografia JSF](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=criptografia+jsf&oq=crip&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l4.2228j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) no Google e encontrei vários links. Inclusive vídeo em português. Todavia, **acho** que é indiferente ser JSF ou MVC ou qualquer outra coisa.

Comment: Você pode usar a lib [Bcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/). // criptografando password = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt()); // verificando se são a mesma senha BCrypt.checkpw(password, userCheck.getPassword(); // retorna true/false Atualmente uso ela nos meus projetos java, bastante segura, um detalhe é que de nenhuma forma você consegue descriptografar a senha. Você só consegue comparar uma String, com uma senha já criptografada